# Simplify and global assumptions

Tags: simplifying-expressions, assumptions

I wanna make global assumptions

```
 $Assumptions = A \[Element] Reals && B \[Element] Reals
```

Then I wanna simplify

```
 FullSimplify[Re[1/(A + B)]]
```

I get output

```
 Re[1/(A + B)]
```

I wanna get output

```
 1/(A + B)
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Learn about `ComplexExpand`; that's what you are probably looking for...

Comment: Add the assumption `A + B != 0`?  Sometimes the transformations used by `Simplify` balk if the result could be nonnumeric, or so it seems to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the assumption `A + B != 0` works with `FullSimplify`, too:

```
Simplify[Re[1/(A + B)], A ∈ Reals && B ∈ Reals && A + B != 0]

(*  1/(A + B)  *)
```

Sometimes the transformations used by `Simplify` and `FullSimplify` balk if the result could be nonnumeric, or so it seems to me.